# Google error 500 caldav

Tags: google-calendar

iCal, today, is getting a rather alarming error from Google:

> The server responded with “HTTP/1.1
>   500 Server error code: e00824d7” to
>   operation
>   CalDAVWriteEntityQueueableOperation.

What could this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Http error 500 represents an internal server error.

You may have discovered a bug within google calendar or perhaps you're just experiencing some temporary downtime.